# How are addresses being used to find position?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, 2d

When I cout &elem or &list separately I get their addresses. How does subtracting them give you an int?

```
vector<int> list;
for(auto& elem:list) { 
int i = elem;
int pos = &elem-&list[0]; // pos contains the position in the vector 

// also a &-operator overload proof alternative (thanks to ildjarn) :
// int pos = addressof(elem)-addressof(list[0]); 

}
```

Comment: `for (auto& i : key) cout << i.at(0);`?

Comment: that just gives the first value of i

Comment: @user2419731, please share what you need as output. That is not clear. Above comment should give you want you want.

Comment: my apologies, I thought it was clear. im looking to get output from 0-7.

Comment: `for (size_t i = 0; i < key.size(); i++) { cout << i ; }`